# Simulink model for discrete system of difference equations

Tags: matlab, simulink, discrete-mathematics

I have spent many hours trying to figure Simulink out.  I have included my best attempt and the output graph.  I have created a system of difference equations that simulate how the flu spreads in a population with 3 compartments (Susceptible, Infectious, Recovered (dead or alive included here).  The equations are correct.  Where I am failing is building it correctly.  I do not think my three variables are supposed to reach the extremes.  I believe my infectious was just supposed to be a small bell curve, and the other two shouldn't go from 100% to 0%.  My question is: How can I correctly model this system?  I have tried many variations to make it work.

My equations:

```
s_k+1 = sk - b*tau*i_k*s_k 
i_k+1 = i_k - a*tau*i_k + b*tau*s_k*i_k
r_k+1 = r_k + a*tau*i_k

s_o = 7899990/7900000
i_o = 10/7900000
r_o = 0
```

Here tau = 1, and a and b are arbitrary and can change (values should be around a=`1/3 and b = 1/2 (and I adjust accordingly after).  It is a closed system, nothing is entering or leaving (population stays the same when totaled)

[image: Screenshot of best model and output graph]

Comment: Have you correctly set the initial conditions inside the delay blocks? I'm also confused how you have 6 delay blocks but only 3 parameters... Finally, `a` and `b` might be arbitrary, but please give us example values with the expected output so it's possible to validate any solution!

Comment: As already suggested, you have too many delay blocks, you only need three, something's not right there. Also you are using `s_k` instead of `i_k` in the first equation when doing `b*tau*i_k*s_k`, so you end up with `b*tau*s_k*s_k` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already saw in the comments your model involves too many states. I have set up a correct model of your difference equations.

[image: Model for infection]

---

**Parameters**

```
tau = 1
a = 0.8
b = 2
```